# web2py, Two tables in one form, with image upload

Tags: web2py

I have a problem with two tables in one form. I used the example in the book as a reference but i am inserting an image in the form, it does upload the file but the URL(image name) is all wrong and i do not know how to get it to put the correct url as the image name.

here is My code:

```
db.define_table('forum',
                Field('title','string', unique=True, label=T('Title')),
                Field('body','text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(),label=T('Body')),
                Field('posted_on','datetime',readable=False, writable=False),
                Field('posted_by','reference auth_user',readable=False, writable=False),
                Field('category',db.category))

db.define_table('doc',
                Field('forum_id', 'reference forum',readable=False, writable=False),
                Field('image','upload',uploadfolder=os.path.join(request.folder,'uploads'), autodelete=True),
                Field('posted_on', 'datetime',default=request.now, readable=False, writable=False),
                Field('posted_by','reference auth_user', readable=False, writable=False))


def post():
    form=SQLFORM.factory(db.forum,db.doc)
    db.forum.posted_on.default =request.now
    db.forum.posted_by.default = auth.user
    db.doc.posted_on.default = request.now
    db.doc.posted_by.default= auth.user

    if form.process().accepted:
        id = db.forum.insert(**db.forum._filter_fields(form.vars))
        form.vars.forum_id=id
        id = db.doc.insert(**db.doc._filter_fields(form.vars))
        session.flash='Form Posted'
        redirect(URL('community'))
        redirect
    return dict(form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLFORM.factory()` creates a dummy `DAL` instance with a dummy table (named "no_table" by default). The upload field uses the name of the `DAL` table as part of the new filename when storing the file. The filename should begin with "doc.", but instead will begin with "no_table.". A workaround is to specify the name of the dummy table created by `SQLFORM.factory()`:

```
SQLFORM.factory(db.forum, db.doc, table_name='doc')
```

Obviously that wouldn't work if both tables included upload fields, so you'd need a more sophisticated workaround in that case (that would involve extracting the uploaded files directly from `request.vars` prior to calling `form.process()` -- they can be renamed/stored using the `db.doc.image.store()` method).